# Dashboard report - Transaction/sec

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Can anyone help me to understand how is the Transactions/s calculated in here:

The test is run for 5 mins with 10 users.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So if you look into .jtl results file you will see `timeStamp` column, normally it's the first one.

1. Find `1-Home` request with the earliest timestamp - that will be **start time**
2. Find `1-Home` request with the latest timestamp and add to it the value from the `elapsed` time - that would be **end time**.
3. Subtract start time from the end time - that would be **total time**
4. Divide 88 by that total time - you will get `0.29`

More information:

- [Calculator.getRatePerSecond()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java#L260)
- [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/)